# Is there a calculator that shows what my "potential" odds are?

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds, statistics

I always make the newbie mistake of waiting for the flush or straight. I was wondering if there is a website or an app that, after I put in the two cards in my hand, and then the cards in the flop, it will show me a list of percentages of getting a flush, straight, three of a kind, etc.

I googled, but nothing really came up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to do that with counting your outs.

Comment: There's a reasonable article [here](http://www.pokerology.com/lessons/drawing-odds/) which walks you through it, probably plus several existing questions on this site. I've not been able to find a calculator which outputs odds of specific hands though.

Comment: @Paparazzi, come on. What's so wrong about asking~ Why not start w/ a tool and work my way up.

Comment: @3N1GM4, thanks for the article. It's really good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an android phone you can download "Poker calculator", logo is a clover as you can see topleft. [image: click here for a picture of the app]

It is a great app. It supports hold 'em but also 4 and 5 card omaha high and omaha high/low. You can add multiple players and can input the cards by voice. I recommend it to anyone.